# Show lowest price "as low as" in configurable product - how?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, tierprice

I have a configurable product as mother product, to simple products as child products.

One child product has a tier price for 1,3,5 pieces.

from 1 = 1 €
from 3 = 0.5 €
from 5 = 0.25 €

In my product category view and in the product view only the "as low as 1 €" price is showing.

I have set the tier prices for the customer groups NOT LOGGED IN and GENERAL. Does anyone have an idea how I can show the really lowest possible price?

Best regards